# Check VideoDisplay video is not null in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video

I have datagrid which contains number of rows which have video data.

```
<s:DataGrid id="movieGrid" dataProvider="{movieData}" selectionChange="setSource(event)" />
```

On selection of row get video url and play in VideoDisplay.

```
private function setSource(event:GridSelectionEvent):void
{
    if(videoDisplay!=null)
    {

        var movie:String = movieGrid.selectedItem.flvLink;
        videoDisplay.source = movie;
     }
}
```

And on play select it will play the video.

```
videoDisplay.play();
```

VideoDisplay:

```
<s:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay"  autoPlay="false" />
```

Now that moveData values come from server request.

**Problem:** 
Above works well but,
Some of flvlink are wrong, which does not have videos. 
Now i click on that row which have wrong link and again click on right link row then it have error in videodisplay.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

How, can i skip this error. Is there are anyway i can get that link has video file or not. And if not then not apply source to video display?

**Edit:**

Error comes at `videoPlayer.displayObject` of `videoDisplay` class. In which `displayObject` getting null.

Comment: What do you mean by : "*Some of flvlink are wrong*" ? Is that link not an video URL at all (like example.com/doc.pdf, example.com/dir), or it's an URL of a broken video ? ...

Comment: post the entire error and the relevant code it points to.

Comment: @akmozo Url are broken. means some url fiven like `123.flv` but actually that file are not supported.. And in some situation that file are not in that place.

Comment: @BotMaster this is entire code. on selection of row videodisplay play the video file

Comment: @ketan I'm writing an answer when I see your edit. Yes, I confirm that the problem is coming from the `VideoDisplay.displayObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is fired because the `VideoDisplay.videoObject` is `null` after trying to load a broken video file (or any other non-video content for example).

So to avoid that, you can control a `VideoDisplay` object by code and reinitialize it everytime if `videoObject` is null.

For that, take this example :

```
<s:DataGrid id="movieGrid" dataProvider="{movieData}" selectionChange="playVideo(event)" /> 
<s:Group id="videoDisplayContainer" />
```

And

```
private var videoDisplay:VideoDisplay;

private function initVideoDisplay(): void 
{
    videoDisplay = new VideoDisplay();
    videoDisplay.autoPlay = false;
    videoDisplay.percentWidth = 100;
    videoDisplay.percentHeight = 100;
    videoDisplayContainer.addElement(videoDisplay);
}

protected function playVideo(event:GridSelectionEvent):void
{   
    if(!videoDisplay || !videoDisplay.videoObject){
        initVideoDisplay();
    }
    var movie:String = movieGrid.selectedItem.flvLink;
    try {
        videoDisplay.source = movie;
    } catch(e:Error){
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks, it's very nice solution.